# Merge inheritance realm objects together

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, realm

As you see below i have 2 Realm subclasses `Dog` and `Cag`, which contain a different amount of objects. i want to retrieve these objects and add them together in one array, so i can run the `sortPetByDate`. However i can't `appendTheContentOf`, due to the fact that

```
let cat = realm.objects(Cat)
let dog = realm.objects(Dog)
```

returns `Results<t>`.

What is the best way to run this method on multiple inheritance objects?

```
func sortPetByDate(array:[AnyObject]) -> [AnyObject]     {
    return array.sort{ ($0.0 as! Pet).date.compare(($0.1 as! Pet).date) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending }
}
```

Example of my inheritance classes:

```
class Pet: Object {
    dynamic var date = NSDate()
    dynamic var title = String()
}

class Dog: Pet {
}

class Cat: Pet {
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Realm [doesn't support polymorphic queries yet](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1109).

So you would need to query for both object types separately.

```
let cat = realm.objects(Cat)
let dog = realm.objects(Dog)
```

Depending on your use-case, you could just pull them all in memory and append them both to an array of `[Object]` and then simply sort that array.
That would look like below:

```
var pets = [Object]()
pets += dogs.map { $0 as Pet }
pets += cats.map { $0 as Pet }
var sortedPets = pets.sort { $0.date.compare($1.date) == .OrderedAscending }
```